# How to change the color of a <p> tag in a div class under another <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have some text in my HTML banner "Find out what Google can do for you". I want the color to be #ffffff (white), but for some reason it's picking up the color from the above "p" tag so it shows the color rgb (102, 102, 102). How can I make it so the .box-row p really shows #ffffff.

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/tKn9f/39/

```
        <div id="wrapper-landing">
    <p>
        Google has released an update to its Text-to-Speech app (TTS) that adds new, high-quality voices—that now take up a couple hundred MB worth of space instead of the old 5-6MB—as well as several new language packs including UK English, Portuguese, and US Spanish.</p>
        <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box-form-body">
                <p>
                    Find out what Google can do for you!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-form-button">
            <img alt="Learn More" height="100" src="http://www.robindelillo.fr/img/home/seeMoreButton.png" width="100" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        #wrapper-landing {
        width: 916px;
        margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

        #wrapper-landing p {
            color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
            font-family: 'SegoeRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            line-height: 1.6em;
    }

    .box-row {
        width:915px;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #e2e3e4;
        margin-top:50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color:#f66511;
    }
    .box-row p {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'SegoeRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
}

.box-form-body {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
    .box-form-button {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 15%;
        padding: 0 0 0 2em;
    }
    .box-form-button img {
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

the  `#wrapper-landing p` has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.box-row p` so use:

```
#wrapper-landing .box-row p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKn9f/40/)

Comment: I would go with: `#wrapper-landing .box-form-body p`.

Comment: @skywalker It really depends upon the how the OP wants the site to appear. Maybe he wants the `p` inside all `.box-row` to be white in color OR maybe the selector you specified is more suitable for him.. but i just wanted to clear the concept so that he can use the knowledge and decide whats best for him :)

Comment: I agree, I like to be closer to `p`, feels better :).

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple, you can set your CSS for that

as given below -

```
.box-row p {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: When `!important` should be used: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 0):

## JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".box-form-body").find('p').css({color: '#fff'});   
});
```

## CSS

```
    .box-form-body p {
      color: #ffffff !important;
    }
```

## inline style

```
<p style="color: #fff;"> Find out what Google can do for you!</p>
```

Hope this is helpful!